# In Sublime Text 2, consider hyphen as part of word

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

How can I have a double-click on a word which contains a hyphen (dash) in Sublime Text 2 select the entire word, not just one part of the word delimited by the hyphen?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Click *settings* -> *default settings*, locate the `"word_separators"` key and delete the hyphen from the character set, re-save.

Comment: It's best to copy and paste this setting into User Settings with the appropriate characters removed/added instead of editing the Default Settings.

Comment: If you only want the setting to effect a certain file type (for example css files), open a css file then menu > Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User.

Comment: But then ctrl+d on `a` still matches the `a` in `a-b`. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

As @Nate Pinchot stated, it's better to add the `"word_separators"` key to the User Settings. In case of updating Sublime Text the changes in `Default Settings` will be reset.

Go to `Preferences > Settings ̶  Users` and add between the outermost `{}` brackets:

```js
// Characters that are considered to separate words, here without hyphen
"word_separators": "/\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

Don't forget about the comma at the end if it's not the only or last key added.

Comment: The period (dot) cannot be chosen. could you make a simple explanation about "./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?". I noted there is a period in the beginning. Thank you.

Comment: @Zhilong You're right, the `dot` is twice in here, for no reason. I've edited the syntax. For me adding/removing the dot works perfectly in Sublime Text 2.
The only thing you need to know about the syntax is, that backslash \ escapes the following character, in this case once another \, once the quote `"`.

Comment: In ST3 copying the "word-separators" line from default to user preference file and deleting the hyphen `-` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

As @Intentss mentioned (i don't want it lost in the comments), if you only want to modify this behaviour for a specific file type:

Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User.

or in my case

Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific

and then edit the user version that shows up:

`` "word_separators": "/\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?" ``