# How to select hyphens separated words with Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I have variables separated with hyphens and I would like to select them entirely by double-clicking on them on Netbeans.

I just can't find how to set that up...

I know you can with Sublime Text : [In Sublime Text 2, consider hyphen as part of word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416724/in-sublime-text-2-consider-hyphen-as-part-of-word)

UPDATE:
It apparently works for CSS but I'm using SCSS.
Class names, variables and CSS attributes are not selected properly on double click.

```
.navigation-container{   //not properly selected
 #{$nav-middle}{ //not properly selected
      > ul ul{
           align-content: center; //not properly selected
      }
 }
```

Comment: If I double click a variable name with hyphens in a `css` file NetBeans selects the entire name. With which language(s) are you seeing this issue? Update your post with some specific example(s) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for noticing me, I updated the post.

Comment: I don't see a way to fully select a hyphenated variable by double clicking in _.scss_ files. There is a somewhat unsatisfactory alternative though: position the cursor anywhere within the hyphenated variable and press `Alt` + `Shift` + `.`to perform a block selection. Since the initial "code block" is simply the variable name itself, that happens to do what you want (though by luck rather than by design). I realize that does not solve your problem, but I thought I'd mention it in the absence of a true solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. Should I write to Netbeans as a feature request? Do you know if Netbeans 8.2 is still under development or only 9 and 10 are now supported.

Comment: Yes, by all means [create a bug report with Type = New Feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1647?jql=project%20%3D%20NETBEANS%20AND%20text%20~%20%22scss%22). On that bug report you can specify the affected version(s) of NetBeans, though as a practical matter I doubt if any solution will be provided for versions < 10.0 (but that is just a guess on my part). From looking at existing NetBeans bug reports for SCSS/SASS, it seems that you are not the only person looking for new features.